# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'name of assembly' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I was working on my web API using c# and vs 2022 and was publishing it on IIS. Everything was working perfectly until something was wrong with my vs 2022, so I had to go back to vs 2019. Suddenly, I can't publish my service anymore. All I get is this error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\alnahrain\1aa8f4f2\2a3c0bfe\App_global.asax.xj9i95jy.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

stack trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\alnahrain\1aa8f4f2\2a3c0bfe\App_global.asax.xj9i95jy.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +232
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity) +62
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults.get_CompiledAssembly() +119
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +74
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +22
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +12033769
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +52
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +341

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\alnahrain\1aa8f4f2\2a3c0bfe\App_global.asax.xj9i95jy.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +76
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +631
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +38
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +758

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\alnahrain\1aa8f4f2\2a3c0bfe\App_global.asax.xj9i95jy.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +122
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +737
```

What is this about? Is this related to downgrading to vs 2019? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you done a _Build->Clean_ followed by a _Rebuild_?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar error report. This was the workaround-
Check the web.config file, and delete the following lines (example):

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=X.X.X.X, Culture=xxxxxx, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" warningLevel="x" compilerOptions="/langversion:x /nowarn:xxxx;xxxx;xxxx" />
<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" warningLevel="x" compilerOptions="/langversion:xx /nowarn:xxxxx /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

You could refer to this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8760b09c-ebab-488f-bd51-0ea25169ef52/error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly?forum=aspconfiganddeploy